# Average value of smallest dice rolled?

Tags: probability, dice

We roll a dice until we get a $5$. What is the expected value of the smallest dice rolled?

I am looking for a thought process/an idea. Seeing a full solution would be great as well.

Calculating the probability of obtaining $1,\dots, 5$ is what I seem to struggle with. I thought it is simply a Bernoulli distribution, namely that the probability of getting $k$ in the first $i$ throws is simply $1-\left (\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i}$. Intuitively, the more I throw, the more likely I am to get a $1$ or $2$ so these numbers should have a greater *weight* than $3,4,5$. I can't seem to express this mathematically though.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Dealing_with_discrete_variables. The formula is particular simple for the minimum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_i$ be the relevant probability.  So $p_i$  is the probability that the minimal roll is an $i$.

I'll compute $p_1$, the others are similar.

Case I:  First roll is a $6$.  $6$ can not be the minimum rolled, so that roll changes nothing.

Case II:  First roll is a $5$.  Then $5$ is the minimal roll.

Case III.  First roll is a $2,3,4$.  Then the probability that the minimal roll is $1$ is unchanged.

Case IV. First roll is a $1$.  Then the minimal roll is guaranteed to be $1$.

Thus $$p_1=\frac 16\times (p_1+0+3p_1+1)\implies p_1=\frac 12$$

Sanity check:  If we imagine that we keep on rolling after we get the $5$ then either $1$ or $5$ comes first and the probability of either is $\frac 12$.  I expect this argument could be strengthened to compute all the cases.

Comment: Following your sanity check, $P(X\ge k)=\frac1k$ because $X\ge k$ iff $5$ appears first in the random permutation of $1,\ldots, k-1$  and $5$ given by their first appearence in the roll sequence. Then $E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^5 P(X\ge k)=1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Ah, thank you.  I figured there had to be a clear way to see that, but I couldn't make out the details.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts to get you started: Obviously all the rolls *before* the first five cannot be a five.   However, each of those rolls is otherwise independent and unbiased.   Yet last roll *will* be five, thus if all dice rolled *before* the first five do show sixes, the least value will be five.

Let $X$ count the rolls before the first five, and let $Y$ measure the least result rolled (which can be conditioned over $X$).   Find $\mathsf E(Y)$.

Comment: This "Obviously all the rolls before the first five cannot be a five.   However, each of those rolls is otherwise independent and unbiased.   Yet last roll will be five, thus if all dice rolled before the first five do show sixes, the least value will be five."  I had already figured out. I guess where my problem comes is how to find out what the probability is to get $1,\dots,5$ I thought it was simply a Bernoulli distribution for each of them, but something doesn't seem right. Would you be able to offer any hints on that?

Comment: Evaluate $\mathsf P(Y\geq y\mid X=x)$ as the probability for the minimum result being $y$ or more when given that $x$ die are rolled before the first five.

Comment: $\mathsf P(Y\geq y)$, found by the law of total probability, will then be a series with a neat closed form, and you can find the expectation from that.  (Hint: what distribution does $X$ have?)  Or you may use lulu's method.

Comment: First comment is very useful. got the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following procedure

1. Set $t\leftarrow a$
2. Roll a die with result $X$.
3. If $X<t$, set $t\leftarrow X$
4. If $X\ne 5$, go back to step 2. Otherwise terminate

Let $f(a)$ be the expected value of $t$ upon termination of the above. We want to find $f(5)$ (or $f(a)$ for any $a\ge5$).
Because the first roll can be either $\color{red}{<a}$ or $\color{green}{=5}$ or ($\color{blue}{\ge a\text{ and }\ne 5}$), we have
$$\begin{align}f(1)&=\color{green}{\frac16\cdot 1}+\color{blue}{\frac56\cdot f(1)}\\
f(2)&=\color{red}{\frac16\cdot f(1)}+\color{green}{\frac16\cdot 2}+\color{blue}{\frac 46\cdot f(2)}\\
f(3)&=\color{red}{\frac16\cdot f(1)+\frac16\cdot f(2)}+\color{green}{\frac16\cdot 3}+\color{blue}{\frac 36\cdot f(3)}\\
f(4)&=\color{red}{\frac16\cdot f(1)+\frac16\cdot f(2)+\frac16\cdot f(3)}+\color{green}{\frac16\cdot 4}+\color{blue}{\frac 26\cdot f(4)}\\
f(5)&=\color{red}{\frac16\cdot f(1)+\frac16\cdot f(2)+\frac16\cdot f(3)+\frac16\cdot f(4)}+\color{green}{\frac16\cdot 5}+\color{blue}{\frac 16\cdot f(5)}\\
\end{align} $$
This can be solved from top to bottom,
$$f(1)=1, f(2)=\frac32, f(3)=\frac{11}6,f(4)=\frac{25}{12}, $$
and finally
$$ f(5)=\frac{137}{60}.$$